# php call array from string

Tags: php, arrays

I have a string that contains elements from array.

```
$str = '[some][string]';
$array = array();
```

How can I get the value of `$array['some']['string']` using `$str`?

Comment: I think what you're trying to do wouldn't be very good practice anyway. Better to do `$array[$key1][$key2]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do so by using eval, don't know if your comfortable with it:

```
$array['some']['string'] = 'test';    
$str = '[some][string]';    
$code = sprintf('return $array%s;', str_replace(array('[',']'), array('[\'', '\']'), $str));    
$value = eval($code);    
echo $value; # test
```

However eval is not always the right tool because well, it shows most often that you have a design flaw when you need to use it.

Another example if you need to write access to the array item, you can do the following:

```
$array['some']['string'] = 'test';
$str = '[some][string]';
$path = explode('][', substr($str, 1, -1));
$value = &$array;
foreach($path as $segment)
{
    $value = &$value[$segment];
}

echo $value;
$value = 'changed';
print_r($array);
```

This is actually the same principle as in [Eric's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6981188/php-call-array-from-string/6981250#6981250) but referencing the variable.

Comment: If he isn't comfortable with it, he shouldn't be storing the string that way.

Comment: @Eric: Don't know, but your solution looks much nicer :)

Comment: Its perfect.I've already tried with eval, but I didn't make it really well.

Answer (score 4):

This will work for any number of keys:

```
$keys = explode('][', substr($str, 1, -1));
$value = $array;
foreach($keys as $key)
    $value = $value[$key];

echo $value
```

Comment: Actually, this is the best case.I won't remove the accepted from @hakre, but I gave you+.Thanks to all that have participated!

Comment: @Daniel: Care to elaborate?

Comment: @Eric No need for that :)

Comment: Gaah, @BobGregor edited it and broke it (replacing `$array` with `array()`

Answer (score 1):

```
// trim the start and end brackets    
$str = trim($str, '[]');
// explode the keys into an array
$keys = explode('][', $str);
// reference the array using the stored keys
$value = $array[$keys[0][$keys[1]];
```

Comment: Hi, what about bigger arrays? Anyway thanks for the response!

Comment: Bigger arrays weren't part of the original question!

Answer (score 0):

I think regexp should do the trick better:

```
$array['some']['string'] = 'test';
$str = '[some][string]';
if (preg_match('/\[(?<key1>\w+)\]\[(?<key2>\w+)\]/', $str, $keys))
{
    if (isset($array[$keys['key1']][$keys['key2']]))
         echo $array[$keys['key1']][$keys['key2']]; // do what you need
}
```

But I would think twice before dealing with arrays your way :D