# Acessing an multidimentional array from a variable

Tags: php

I want to store the parents keys of an array so I can access it later.

Something like:

```
$arr['hello'][0]['world'] = 'a';
$arr['hello'][1]['world'] = 'b';
```

And store both hello, 0 and world as some kind of variable so I can access the array with it:

For example, something I would think it may work is:

```
$indexes = array('hello', 0, 'world');
$arr[$indexes]
```

But this doesn't work, as an array is an illegal offset type for another array. So is there a way to access an array by an array of parents keys (variable)?

Comment: not sure what the actual question is

Comment: I am asking if I can, somehow, access and array by only knowing their keys, but that can be of any depth, will try to change the question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [php call array from string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6981188/php-call-array-from-string) - there is another dupe I know of which is even more duplicate, but I could not find it that quickly. The principle how this works is always the same.

Answer (score 0):

i think you want

```
echo $array[{$one}][{$two}];
```

Comment: as I explained on a similar answer below.. no.. I don't know the depth of the array, it can be of any depth, not just two or three. It's a dynamic built array and I am storing parents keys and I want to access them later.

Comment: sorry that just sounds like poor design.

Comment: what's the purpose? keyword search?

Answer (score 0):

So do you want to access a child array by a custom key that occurs in a parent array?

```
$parent_array[$custom_key] = array('hello',0,'world');
```